# How to get index of elem inside a container based on similar classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing, each

I'm trying to calculate an object's `index` value based on children's object's similar classes, not by `tag` name.

Think there is a seperator container betwee `type_a` and `type_b` elements. I wrote `index` values which i'm trying to get, but can't find a way to solve this.

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/F5E76/)

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="type_a">0</span>
    <span class="type_a">1</span>
    <span class="type_b">0</span>
    <span class="type_a">2</span>
    <span class="type_b">1</span>
    <span class="type_b active">2</span>
    <span class="type_a">3</span>
    <span class="type_a">4</span>
    <span class="type_b">3</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.container .type_b').each(function(index) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        console.log($(this).index());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
console.log($('.container .type_b').index($('.active')));
```

Will log the correct index.

Comment: very nice and short solution +1 from me mate (:

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
$('.container .type_b').each(function(index) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        console.log(index);
    }
});
```